# Работа _popen(); в С++

Tags: windows, c++

собственно:

```
_popen ("C:\\Windows\\System32\\regedt32.exe", "r");
```

работает, а допустим:

```
_popen ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GRETECH\\GomPlayer\\GOM.exe", "r");
```

Нифига!
Я так понимаю из-за пробелов! Подскажите пожалуйста как прописывать такие пути?

Comment: avp, alexlz, спасибо работает!) Я сделал программно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте весь путь в кавычки заключить. Если писать в программе, то popen ("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GRETECH\\GomPlayer\\GOM.exe\"", "r");

Но лучше программно:

```
sprintf (exe_it,"\"%s\"",path_to_pgm); popen(exe_it,"r");
```

Наверное так cmd поймет.

Answer (score 1):

Да уж. Попробуйте заключать в апосторофы, ну вроде

```
_popen("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GRETECH\\GomPlayer\\GOM.exe\"", "r');
```

Проверять самому ну просто лениво -- мороки много.